# Making a lot of requests with MySQL while trying to keep good performace

Tags: php, mysql

This is what the code does:

1. Check if the user's website exists and is active.
2. After checking the user IP already exists and if the weather 24 hours have passed, if so it deletes the IP database.
3. Check if there is an ads in the database
4. Insert a view in the database, insert the ip database

```php
<?php 
    require_once("../mysql/configurations.php");
    $type     = addslashes($_GET["type"]);
    $userid   = addslashes($_GET["user_id"]);
    $siteid   = addslashes($_GET["site_id"]);
    $status   = "Active";
    $user_ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $isp      = gethostbyaddr($user_ip);
    $time     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $time_now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $dataI    = date('Y-m-d');
    openConnection(); 
    $stmt0 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM web WHERE id=? AND userid =? AND status=?"); 
    $stmt0->bind_param('iis', $siteid, $userid, $status);
    $stmt0->execute();
    $stmt0->store_result();
    if($stmt0->num_rows == true) {
        $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip=? AND expired > ?"); // >
        $stmt1->bind_param('ss', $user_ip, $time_now);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $res = $stmt1->get_result();
        if($res->num_rows >= 1) {
            $res->data_seek($row_no);
            $get = $res->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt2  = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ips WHERE id=?");
            $stmt2->bind_param("i", $get["id"]);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->close();
            $res->close();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
            echo include("show.php");
        } else {
            $stmt3    = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip=?");
            $stmt3->bind_param("s", $user_ip);
            $stmt3->execute();
            $res = $stmt3->get_result();
            if($res->num_rows == 1) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
                echo include("show.php");
                session_destroy();   
            } else {
                $browser  = getBrowser();
                $tipo     = "Click";
                $status   = "Active";
                $value    = 0.30;
                $stmt4 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM a WHERE tipo=? AND saldo > ? AND status=? AND formato=? ORDER by RAND()");
                $stmt4->bind_param("sdss", $tipo, $value, $status, $type);
                $stmt4->execute();
                $res = $stmt4->get_result();
                if($res->num_rows == 1) {
                    error_reporting(true);
                    $res->data_seek($row_no);
                    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
                    $vv = $row["ecpm"];
                    $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE a SET views=views+1, gastos=gastos+?, saldo=saldo-? WHERE id=?");
                    $stmt5->bind_param("ddi", $vv, $vv, $row["id"]);
                    $stmt5->execute();
                    $stmt8 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ips (ip, expired, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt8->bind_param("sss", $user_ip, next_data(1), $time);
                    $stmt8->execute(); 
                    $stmt8->close();
                    $stmt5->close();
                    $res->close();
                    $sql4 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM views WHERE siteid=? AND userid=? AND date=?");
                    $sql4->bind_param("iis", $siteid, $userid, $dataI);
                    $sql4->execute();
                    $res = $sql4->get_result();
                    if($res->num_rows == 1) {
                        $sql5 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE views SET views=views+1, value=value+? WHERE siteid=? AND userid=? AND date=?");
                        $sql5->bind_param("diis", $vv, $siteid, $userid, $dataI);
                        $sql5->execute();
                        $sql5->close();
                        $res->close();
                    } else if($res->num_rows >= 2) {
                        while($res->num_rows > 1) {
                            $res->data_seek($row_no);
                            $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
                            $stmt6 = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM views WHERE id=?");
                            $stmt6->bind_param("i", $row["id"]);
                            $stmt6->execute();
                        }
                    } else {
                        $imp = 1;
                        $stmt7 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO views (userid, siteid, date, views, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $stmt7->bind_param("iisid", $userid, $siteid, $dataI, $imp, $vv);
                        $stmt7->execute();
                    }

                } else {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
                    echo include("show.php");
                    session_destroy();   
                }  
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

I'm studying PHP and MySQL and I'd like to know how can I improve this script to better and to use on my website with 1000 concurrent users executing this script.

Comment: @SirPython done

Comment: I almost forgot. There is one more thing that needs to be changed: the title of your post should reflect the function/purpose of your code.

Comment: @SirPython I think now it is ok, right?

Comment: It's better and will do, but it's still a little general.

Comment: I assume you've created INDEXes on the tables/fields?

Comment: I don't know, what is index? sorry I'm noob. I put the 'id' as primary

Comment: Why are you using `addslashes`? That seems unnecessary as you're properly using parameterised statements, and would probably actually introduce incorrect data.

Comment: Note that `gethostbyaddr` can be very, very slow, as it depends on the performance of external DNS servers and/or the links to them.

Comment: @YanSilva If you could show us the schema of your database, I can show you how to create INDEXes on the appropriate columns.

Answer (score 1):

As a first obvious remark you can increase performance using only one query instead of two when looking for IPs. Currently you're doing:

```
    //...
    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip=? AND expired > ?");
    //...
    if($res->num_rows >= 1) {
      //...
      $stmt2  = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ips WHERE id=?");
      //...
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
      echo include("show.php");
    } else {
      $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip=?");
      //...
      if($res->num_rows == 1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
        echo include("show.php");
        //...
```

while you could merely look for IP, then work depending on expired or not at the same time avoiding to repeat :

```
    //...
    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip=?");
    //...
    if($res->num_rows >= 1) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
      echo include("show.php");
      //...
      if ($row['expired'] > $time_now) {
        //...
        $stmt2  = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ips WHERE id=?");
        //...
        $_SESSION["ttt"] = $type;
        echo include("show.php");
      } else {
        //...
```

For the rest of the logics, it seems there is no other noticeable point, though I can't be sure since I don't know the detailed data you work with.